# How to create an Oracle package with private procedure?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper, plsql-package

I'm creating an Oracle package and I wonder if it's possible to make a prcedure private, here is my sample code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE MYSCHEMA.MyPackage AS
 PROCEDURE MyProcedureA(outputParam OUT VARCHAR2);
 PROCEDURE MyProcedureB(inputParam IN VARCHAR2);
END MyPackage;

/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY MYSCHEMA.MyPackage AS

 PROCEDURE MyProcedureA(outputParam OUT VARCHAR2) AS
  myHello VARCHAR2(1000) := 'Hello';
 BEGIN
  MyProcedureB(myHello);
  outputParam := 'OK';
 END MyProcedureA;

 PROCEDURE MyProcedureB(inputParam IN VARCHAR2) AS
  myWorld VARCHAR2(1000) := 'World';
 BEGIN
  dbms_output.put_line(inputParam || myWorld);
 END MyProcedureB;

END MyPackage;
```

is it possible to make MyProcedureB 'private', I means it can be only called by the other procedures within the package (MyProcedureA)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure.  Anything not declared in the package spec is private.

Once you remove `MyProcedureB` from the package spec, however, you it to be declared before it is called in `MyProcedureA`.  I generally prefer to do this by putting the implementation of `MyProcedureB` before the implementation of `MyProcedureA` in the package body.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE MYSCHEMA.MyPackage AS
 PROCEDURE MyProcedureA(outputParam OUT VARCHAR2);
END MyPackage;

/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY MYSCHEMA.MyPackage AS

 PROCEDURE MyProcedureB(inputParam IN VARCHAR2) AS
  myWorld VARCHAR2(1000) := 'World';
 BEGIN
  dbms_output.put_line(inputParam || myWorld);
 END MyProcedureB;

 PROCEDURE MyProcedureA(outputParam OUT VARCHAR2) AS
  myHello VARCHAR2(1000) := 'Hello';
 BEGIN
  MyProcedureB(myHello);
  outputParam := 'OK';
 END MyProcedureA;

END MyPackage;
```

You could also leave the order as you have it and just declare the spec for the procedure at the top of the package body

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE MYSCHEMA.MyPackage AS
 PROCEDURE MyProcedureA(outputParam OUT VARCHAR2);
END MyPackage;

/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY MYSCHEMA.MyPackage AS
 PROCEDURE MyProcedureB(inputParam IN VARCHAR2);

 PROCEDURE MyProcedureA(outputParam OUT VARCHAR2) AS
  myHello VARCHAR2(1000) := 'Hello';
 BEGIN
  MyProcedureB(myHello);
  outputParam := 'OK';
 END MyProcedureA;

 PROCEDURE MyProcedureB(inputParam IN VARCHAR2) AS
  myWorld VARCHAR2(1000) := 'World';
 BEGIN
  dbms_output.put_line(inputParam || myWorld);
 END MyProcedureB;

END MyPackage;
```